# Can't understand apperantly simple code snippet in C# using RegexClass r = new Regex(" |, |,");

Tags: c#, regex

I have problems with some code that should be simple.

```
namespace CSharp
{
    using System;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    public class Tester
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string s1 = "One,Two,Three Liberty Associates, Inc.";
            Regex theRegex = new Regex(" |, |,");
            StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            int id = 1;
            foreach (string subString in theRegex.Split(s1))
            {
                sBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}: {1}\n", id++, subString);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", sBuilder);
        }
    }//tester class
}//namespace
```

Which outputs:

```
1: One
2: Two
3: Three
4: Liberty
5: Associates
6: Inc.
```

If I modify the constructor call to new Regex(" |, ");
I get:

```
1: One,Two,Three
2: Liberty
3: Associates
4: Inc.
```

I know | is or and I am parsing with , and space, but I don't understand how it works and why I need it given twice.

Comment: The pipe is the regex OR match, so your regular expression is splitting on a space, a comma followed by a space, or a comma.

Answer (score 0):

You can think about "|" as OR. So, when breakdown this regex, you find all matches with this pattern: " "  OR ", " OR ",".

Answer (score 0):

The second regex has space OR comma-plus-space. The string "One,Two,Three" does not have any spaces so does not match any part of that regex. To better see what is happening try `Regex("( |, |,)")` and `Regex("( |, )")`. Adding the capture brackets into the regexs adds the text they match into the results. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?view=netframework-4.8) which states:

> If capturing parentheses are used in a Regex.Split expression, any captured text is included in the resulting string array. For example, if you split the string "plum-pear" on a hyphen placed within capturing parentheses, the returned array includes a string element that contains the hyphen.

Additionally, I suggest changing the

```
sBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}: {1}\n", id++, subString);
```

to be

```
sBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}: '{1}'\n", id++, subString);
```

Enclosing the `{1}` in quotes makes the string easier to see, especially if it has leading or trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Your first regex " |, |," split the text by three options:

- one space (' ')
- one comma (',')
- one comma and one space (', ')

The second regex " |, " have only two options:

- one space (' ')
- one comma and one space (', ')

The split by comma not exists so it don't split the "One,Two,Three".

I suggest change `' '` with `\s` and you can take the two options `','` and `', '` with this code: `',\s?'` - one comma and then one or zero spaces.

So the full regex is: `"\s|,\s?"`

you can check it here: [regex](https://regex101.com/r/JrLiBu/1)

Comment: Regex theReg = new Regex(@"(\S+)\s"); and how does this one work? \S is non=space character, \s is space character, and the + means at least one char or? and why is it put in parantheses? (\S+)

Answer (score 0):

ok so how does the following work?

```
 Regex theReg = new Regex(@"(?<time>(\d|\:)+)\s" + @"(?<ip>(\d|\.)+)\s" +
                             @"(?<site>\S+)");
```

@"(?(\d|:)+)\s" - should mean a group called time that has any combination of numbers and : colons right?
@"(?(\d|.)+)\s" - a group called IP that has numbers or dots in any amount

@"(?\S+)") - a group of character

And the way this Regex is designed to work, it only works in pairs of 3 or? made a few tests with it, this is what I understand.

Comment: This reads like a new question rather than an answer. If it is an answer to your original question then please [edit] it to make it clear that it is an answer. If it is a question then then it should not be here as an answer, please write a new question.

Comment: Wanted to post it simply as a new post in this topic, no point in creating a new one, they are directly related, wanted to get a simple answer form the same ppl. Anyhow I think I kind of understood it right.

Comment: This is not a forum, it is not a chatty site with topics. This is a Q&A site. You should take the [tour] to learn about how this site works.